# Deployed Azure Serverless Function does not see classes besides Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have developed an Azure Serverless Function in Eclipse.
The function works locally (Run As/Maven/Set Goals=test) but does not work once deployed.
It fails with the following error

```
[Error] Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Failed, Id=0de9ae96-68c6-4620-ba05-63a1c1c99b97, 
Duration=24ms)
Result: FailureException: NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/servlet/http/HttpServletStack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at
```

I can see from looking at the code that it is failing at the following line.

```
boolean tokenVerified = RecaptchaVerification.verifyRecaptchaSite(token);
```

This is the first line in the code that references a class not in `Function.java`

Here is the structure of the code in Eclipse

[image]

I have used WinSCP and the publish profile credentials to examine what has been deployed.

Everything is there

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?
I could put all the code into Function.java and this would work, but I would prefer to solve this properly. (Incidentally the same issue happened to me when I did development in Visual Studio Code)

**UPDATE:**
I tried the following also - but to no avail.

1. I tried running on Java 11 instead of Java 8 (with appropriate changes to the pom.xml file) and trying different versions of `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`.
2. I made sure the `artifactID` was different from the `functionAppName`, and that both were in lowercase.
3. I tried updating the `javax.servlet` version in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that because the *first* call to classes outside of `function.java` failed, all others would fail as well. However the problem was peculiar to `RecaptchaVerification.java`.

The class that I tried to call looked like this.

```
public class RecaptchaVerification extends HttpServlet {
  /**
    *
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SECRET_PARAM = "xxx";
    private static final String RESPONSE_PARAM = "xxxx";
```

If I removed the `extends HttpServlet` then everything works. Note that I do not know why this solves the problem - I do not think that I should have known this from the error message of `NoClassDefFoundError`.

(In retrospect I should have posted the code to `RecaptchaVerification.java` as well in my question)